# Декодер повторений в строке

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты

Иногда замечаю в решениях некоторых задач довольно странную конструкцию:

```
Object[key] = (Object[key] || 0) + 1;
```

И вот она вновь попалась при решении очередной задачи, суть которой звучит так:

> Переработайте строку так, чтобы каждый уникальный её элемент был обозначен "(", а повторения ")".

Парочка примеров:

```
"din"      =>  "((("
"recede"   =>  "()()()"
```

Собственно, решение, которое меня смутило:

```js
const duplicateEncode = (word) => {
   let letterCount = {};
   let letters = word.toLowerCase().split("");
   letters.forEach((letter) => {
      letterCount[letter] = (letterCount[letter] || 0) + 1;
   });
   return letters.map((letter) => {
  if (letterCount[letter] === 1) {
  return "(";
     } else {
     return ")";
     }
  }).join("");
};
```

Что происходит в этой строке `letterCount[letter] = (letterCount[letter] || 0) + 1;`? В Объекте letterCount устанавливается ключ letter но что означает его значение? Не понимаю как это работает. Видел в консоли, мол в качестве ключа устанавливается сам символ, а значением его количество повторений. Опять же, я не понимаю как так получилось. Помогите проанализировать данный момент, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строка `letterCount[letter] = (letterCount[letter] || 0) + 1;` примерно равна:

```
if (letterCount[letter] != undefined)
    letterCount[letter] = letterCount[letter] + 1;
else
    letterCount[letter] = 0 + 1;
```

т.е. она позволяет создать сзачение по-умолчанию, если у нас `letterCount[letter]` не существует, чтобы не получать `NaN` пытаясь сложить `undefined + 1`.

Это работает потому что в JS оператор `||` возвращает значение операнда (а не результат его конвертирования в bool), который истинный (`== true`, `!= null`, `!= undefined`, `!= 0`), т.е. в выражении `letterCount[letter] || 0` если левая часть истинна (`!= undefined`), то будет возвращен результат `letterCount[letter]`, если нет, то 0 ([Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical)).